# why ecx is pushed to the stack twice,just one after another?

Tags: assembly

Here, in this function prologue ecx is pushed to the stack twice one after another, Why??

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp

push    ecx
push    ecx
and     [ebp+var_8], 0
and     [ebp+var_4], 0
push    ebx
mov     ebx, [ebp+arg_0]
push    esi
push    edi
or      edi, 0FFFFFFFFh
push    edi             ; size_t
lea     eax, [ebp+var_8]
push    eax             ; int
mov     eax, [ebp+arg_4]
call    sub_671FF38E
push    2Eh             ; wchar_t
lea     esi, [ebp+var_8]
call    sub_673AFD82
cmp     eax, edi
jz      loc_677E564B
```

Comment: The best guess is that the routine is of form `void func(int n, ...) { int a=n, b=n, c=... ; func2(...); };` and where some parameter -- not necessarily the first -- is passed in ecx.

Comment: Another guess is that it is just to reserve space on the stack, and that two pushes is shorter than `sub esp, 8`.

Answer (score 4):

Bo is right, it's to allocate the stack - you can see that the stack locations are being zeroed out in the next two instructions, so the ecx value is not actually used. You see this pattern in MSVC-compiled files very often.

Answer (score 2):

It is just getting stack space.

sub esp, 8 -> 3bytes.

push ecx X 2 -> 2bytes.